# MySQL - Return everyone who doesn't have booking?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get MySQL to return me all instructors who don't have a booking at a certain time. This query is essentially the search query. So return all instructors and their details that aren't already booked basically. Could someone help me finish it off?

```
SELECT
  AddressTypes.AddressTypeName,
  Addresses.*,
  InstructorSettings.*,
  Users.*,
  BookedSlots.DateTime
FROM Users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN InstructorSettings
    ON Users.UserID = InstructorSettings.UserID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Addresses
    ON Users.UserID = Addresses.UserID
  INNER JOIN AddressTypes
    ON Addresses.AddressTypeID = AddressTypes.AddressTypeID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BookedSlots
    ON Users.UserID = BookedSlots.UserID
WHERE Users.AccountTYpe = 3 AND Addresses.PostCode1 IN ('l13') AND BookedSlots.DateTime <> '2013-04-25 11:00:00'
```

The query above doesn't return anything, but if I take out the "AND BookedSlots.DateTime <> '2013-04-25 11:00:00'" it returns all the instructors details fine.

Database

[image]

Comment: do you have data in BookedSlots.DateTime that is not null and not '2013-04-25 11:00:00' ?

Comment: Lots of detail here, great stuff; +1. If you want to make things even easier for people to answer, consider adding a SQLFiddle example for forking.

Comment: Regarding the "BookedSlots.DateTime", if a person is signed up for the class, are they ALL stamped with the ex: 11:00:00 timestamp for a particular date you are interested in...  And please confirm this.  Are you really asking for "I want a list of all instructors that are AVAILABLE for the date in question (2013-04-25) who do not have anyone registered for the 11:00:00 session. (they may be occupied for a 12:30, 1:00, 2:00, whatever session, but nothing for the 11:00 session).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if what you're looking for is the *lack of existence of records* in BookedSlots for the specified time.

I'm not sure if this is considered MySQL best practices, but I typically accomplish that task not with a `join`, but with a sub-select or a temp table, like so:

```
SELECT
  AddressTypes.AddressTypeName,
  Addresses.*,
  InstructorSettings.*,
  Users.*,
FROM Users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN InstructorSettings
    ON Users.UserID = InstructorSettings.UserID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Addresses
    ON Users.UserID = Addresses.UserID
  INNER JOIN AddressTypes
    ON Addresses.AddressTypeID = AddressTypes.AddressTypeID
WHERE Users.AccountType = 3 AND Addresses.PostCode1 IN ('l13') 
AND Users.UserID not in (SELECT BookedSlots.InstructorID FROM BookedSlots 
     WHERE BookedSlots.DateTime = '2013-04-25 11:00:00')
```

EDIT: per comments, changed the select statement to disclude BookedSlots, and the sub-select to return InstructorId (which matches instructors instead of students on the booking).

Comment: Hi, This looks like along the lines of what im looking for, but phpMyAdmin returned: `#1051 - Unknown table 'Users'`. Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: That's a strange error, as you have a Users table correct? I tried editing my answer slightly, perhaps give it another go?

Comment: Hi, This time I got `#1054 - Unknown column 'BookedSlots.DateTime' in 'field list'`. Yes there is a Users table, the fields can be seen in the link above.  Thanks very much for helping me.

Comment: Interesting, your parser appears to dislike nicknames for tables... Editing again, report back with findings :)

Comment: Hi Will, Still getting the same error. I tried dbForge to see if that would parse it and it says theres an error on line 6, Unknown Identifier. I removed line 6 `(which is BookedSlots.DateTime)` and got the software to re add it and it changes the "FROM" section to `FROM BookedSlots,
     Users`. I then ran this query and it returned the instructor even though they are already booked for that date and time :S.

Comment: Oh yes, I still had the BookedSlots in the select! Good move removing that, but having it re-added like you did isn't what you want. Edited again, see what happens

Comment: Hi Will, I feel we are getting closer haha :) At first I got an error, but thats because there was an additional comma after Users. I removed this and the query executed, but it still showed the Instructor up, even though he has a booking. I then changed the sub query to `BookedSlots.InstructorID` which SEEMS to now be working. But would you mind checking if that is correct? The UserID field in BookedDates is for the learner, the instructorID is for the instructor but is essentially his userID. Does this make sense?

Comment: Sounds like exactly what you wanted! I wasn't inspecting closely enough to see that instructorID was a field there, well done!

Answer (score 0):

To check that there aren't  any bookings on a particular timeslot, include the timeslot in the join conditions and select where the timeslot id is null - like so:

```
SELECT
  AddressTypes.AddressTypeName,
  Addresses.*,
  InstructorSettings.*,
  Users.*,
  BookedSlots.DateTime
FROM Users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN InstructorSettings
    ON Users.UserID = InstructorSettings.UserID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Addresses
    ON Users.UserID = Addresses.UserID
  INNER JOIN AddressTypes
    ON Addresses.AddressTypeID = AddressTypes.AddressTypeID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BookedSlots
    ON Users.UserID = BookedSlots.UserID AND 
                      BookedSlots.DateTime = '2013-04-25 11:00:00'
WHERE Users.AccountTYpe = 3 AND 
      Addresses.PostCode1 IN ('l13') AND 
      BookedSlots.UserID is null
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks very much for your help. Unfortunately it returned the instructors even if they did have a booking with the date / time above. I tried altering it to `BookedSlots.DateTime <> '2013-04-25 11:00:00'` to no avail.

Comment: @user2317376: I've just noticed that your existing query (and my amended version) is based on finding **`Users`** that don't have a booking on `2013-04-25 11:00:00`, not **`Instructors`**. Do you have an `Instructors` table? (If so, it doesn't appear in either your existing query or your database diagram.)